# error getting in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to build dynamic query for page compression, but at the time of execution it is showing an error.

```
alter PROCEDURE usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase
@dbName VARCHAR(256)
AS
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @gettableName CURSOR
 SET @gettableName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT tablename
FROM table_list
OPEN @gettableName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @gettableName INTO @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + '
ALTER TABLE '+@tableName+' REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH 
(DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE
)'
exec (@varSQL)

FETCH NEXT
FROM @gettableName INTO @tableName
END
 CLOSE @gettableName
DEALLOCATE @gettableName

GO
EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase '[AdventureWorks2014]'
GO
```

Which is giving an error:

> Msg 16943, Level 16, State 4, Procedure
>   usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase, Line 50
>
> Could not complete cursor operation because the table schema changed
>   after the cursor was declared.

How to solve this???

Comment: Do you know which table is this error for? Is it for every table or for a particular table. try printing the @VarSQL before executing it.

Comment: don't change the table schema after the cursor is declared. i.e. don't build a cursor on the table you are changing, so put the list of tables in some other table.

Comment: You may build long script (even without cursor) and execute this whole script with all tables in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT,  
    @PageNumber INT,  
    @FirstRow INT,  
    @LastRow INT  

SELECT  @PageSize = 20,  
          @PageNumber = 1     


SELECT  @FirstRow = ( @PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1,  
    @LastRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + @PageSize ;  

WITH Members  AS  
(  
    SELECT  Col1,Col2,Col3,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS RowNumber  
                FROM    Table  
)  
SELECT  Col1,Col2,..,..,..,
FROM    Members  
WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN @FirstRow AND @LastRow  
ORDER BY Col1 ASC;
```

Use this. This may help you. :)

Comment: Sorry, but how is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

- you can't change the schema or structure of a table if that table is handled by a cursor.
- In the query you are trying to alter the structure of the table when the cursor of that table is active.
- If you want to alter table structure just do it before declaring cursor or after deallocating the cursor.